# Generate an N-digit random number

Tags: php, security, random, mcrypt

I want to generate a 6 digit random number using the PHP `mt_rand()` function.

I know the PHP `mt_rand()` function only takes 2 parameters: a *minimum* and a *maximum* value.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
<?php 
$a = mt_rand(100000,999999); 
?>
```

Or this, then the first digit can be 0 in first example can it only be 1 to 9

```
for ($i = 0; $i<6; $i++) 
{
    $a .= mt_rand(0,9);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> You can use the following code.

```
  <?php 
  $num = mt_rand(100000,999999); 
  printf("%d", $num);
  ?>
```

Here mt_rand(min,max);
min =  Specifies the lowest number to be returned.
max = Specifies the highest number to be returned.

`

Answer (score 4):

```
    <?php
//If you wanna generate only numbers with min and max length:
        function intCodeRandom($length = 8)
        {
          $intMin = (10 ** $length) / 10; // 100...
          $intMax = (10 ** $length) - 1;  // 999...

          $codeRandom = mt_rand($intMin, $intMax);

          return $codeRandom;
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Examples:

```
print rand() . "<br>"; 
//generates and prints a random number
print rand(10, 30); 
//generates and prints a random number between 10 and 30 (10 and 30 ARE included)
print rand(1, 1000000); 
//generates and prints a random number between on and one million
```

[More Details](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_math_rand.asp)

Answer (score 1):

If the first member nunmber can be zero, then you need format it to fill it with zeroes, if necessary.

```
<?php 
$number = mt_rand(10000,999999);
printf("[%06s]\n",$number); // zero-padding works on strings too
?>
```

Or, if it can be form zero, you can do that, to:

```
<?php 
$number = mt_rand(0,999999);
printf("[%06s]\n",$number); // zero-padding works on strings too
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

as far as understood, it should be like that;

```
function rand6($min,$max){
    $num = array();

    for($i=0 ;i<6;i++){
    $num[]=mt_rand($max,$min);

    }
return $num;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it inline like this:

```
$randomNumbersArray = array_map(function() {
    return mt_rand(); 
}, range(1,6));
```

Or the simpliar way, with a function:

```
$randomNumbersArray = giveMeRandNumber(6);

function giveMeRandNumber($count)
{
    $array = array();
    for($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++) {
        $array[] = mt_rand(); 
    }
}
```

These will produce an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1410367617
    [1] => 1410334565
    [2] => 97974531
    [3] => 2076286
    [4] => 1789434517
    [5] => 897532070
)
```