# How to generate x digit random number?

Tags: php

I have to generate 16 digit random number something like recharg card pin number.(including 0 at starting place)
This is my code

```
function gen_num($len) {
    $rand   = '';
    while(!(isset($rand[$len-1]))){
        $rand   .= mt_rand(0,9);
    }
    return substr( $rand , 0 , $len );
}
```

It works fine but takes time to generate.if i want to generate 1000 pin at a same time like

```
foreach($i=0;$i<=1000;$i++){
 get_num(16)
}
```

It takes more time.What is the best way to generate this kind of pin?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How I can generate 6 random numbers - php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990752/how-i-can-generate-6-random-numbers-php)

Comment: check i have updated my ans

Comment: Superfast way `for($i=0;$i<1000;$i++)  echo mt_rand(100000000,999999999).mt_rand(1000000,9999999).'<br/>';`

Answer (score 4):

you may try this function.this will work fine.

```
function getRandomNumber($len = "15")
{
    $better_token = $code=sprintf("%0".$len."d", mt_rand(1, str_pad("", $len,"9")));
    return $better_token;
}

for($i=0;$i<=1000;$i++){
    $codes[]=getRandomNumber(16);
}
```

in $code array you will get all 16 digit number with including 0.Output will be generated like below

```
Array
(
    [0] => 6432618102990092
    [1] => 5412363498471678
    [2] => 8415870470926167
    [3] => 2724858690053225
    [4] => 3719462379813195
    [5] => 0322053456788270
    [6] => 5085590323433281
    [7] => 3586620986461640
    [8] => 5041978429071606
    [9] => 0722051602788270
.....
```

Comment: Why would this be faster? Have you actually measured it?

Comment: this forces it to always start with `0`, but the OP said `including 0 at starting place`, so `0-9` is a valid starting number.

Comment: Yeah , you are right !! Sverri M. Olsen. Thanks!! Let me change it

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = '';
      for ($i = 0; $i<16; $i++) 
    {
        $a .= mt_rand(0,9);
    }
```

you can use this function for generate random number.

> it's possible to same number generate twise so you can put this number in array and check in array number is already there or not.

```
    function gen_num() {
        $rand   = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i<15; $i++) 
            {
                $rand .= mt_rand(0,9);
            }
        return $rand;
    }



foreach($i=0;$i<=1000;$i++){
 echo get_num();
}
```

o/p

```
1992282192849338
2539119565182977
8186185479424499
9762937534145386
5565837949946845
6487684896937977
1437518184397774
1586381543857153
5673128433587996
4988724673517522
8323477255626612
```

Comment: `generate 16 digit random number` - your method would not provide a 16 digit number, as `1` could be return from your `rand()`, which is 15 digits too short.

Comment: now your answer will always start with `0`. Do you have something wrong with `1-9` in the 1st position?

Comment: no it's random generate you can use rand(1,9) instead of mt_rand(0,9)

Comment: but you are starting with `$a = 0;`/`$rand   = 0;` and then concatenating to them `$a .=`/`$rand .=` so your 16 digit numbers will always start with `0` using this code, instead of random `0-9` at the start.

Comment: i have updated my ans please check now no 0 come to first

Comment: ya i got it @Sean i have change my ans

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do just fine:

```
function random_digits($length) {
    $length = intval($length, 10);
    $output = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $output .= mt_rand(0, 9);
    }
    return $output;
}
```