# Get First 3 String Character from username Input and display random number in username field PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Here I want to get the first three string characters from the username input field & generate a random number first 3 characters of the username & random see output to get the expected output

```php
    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" onBlur="?"><br>

    <?php  $ran = rand(1000, 9999); ?>

    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $ran; ?>" placeholder="username">
```

My Expected Output

```
KSA3215
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get first 5 characters from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787540/how-to-get-first-5-characters-from-string)

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990752/generate-an-n-digit-random-number

Comment: i want to get 3 characters from input field values??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13447554/how-to-get-input-field-value-using-php

Comment: Are you fetching any value for input filed dynamicly

Comment: just want to insert Firstname from input field --like --when put KASHIF input field  then KAS will display on username field?

Comment: Hi i have answer the below quetion in php you can achieve it using ajax or javascript on blur method

Answer (score 0):

Hi will you try below code if it fullfills your requirement.

```
<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname"><br>

<?php  
     $ran = rand(1000,9999); 
     $firstThreeChar=substr("yourstring",0,2);
     $restring=$firstThreeChar.$ran;
?>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $restring; ?>" placeholder="username">
```

Comment: but username field get string from Firstname input field? can we change this ? user can add his/her name then username auto generate??

Comment: Yes that will work only when you will use ajax . if you don want to use ajax you can done it using javascript event onblur .

Comment: onblur event you to use the substring(1, 4); method of javascript string and Math.random mehtod. and concatenate the result

Comment: Can you send me any link? when user put username and click tab button auto random number will generate on the Username input field  ---in this I have 2 input fields First for the Name where user input his name and I want to get random values on username field when click on tab button ? Can you please send me any relevant link fo this ?